# Sports competition team gaming

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorial-game-theory, combinations

Let $A,B,C,D,E,F$ be six teams in a sports competition, and each team will play exactly once with another team.

Now we know that Team $A,B,C,D,E$ had already played $5,4,3,2,1$ games, correspondingly.

So, how do I figure out which team haven't played a game with team $B$ yet?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is to fulfill the 30 characters requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A has played all 5 other teams and E has only played one team. That means E must have only played A, so the only team B hasn't played must be E.